# Structured referenced table formula with filtered rows and array formula. New requirements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a few new requirements for this problem that i can't solve:

**Without filter**
[image]

**[#ID]** -> counter of rows

**[value]** -> just a nunch of positives a negatives numbers

**[color]** -> just categorical field

**[negative]** -> 1 when value column is negative 0 when positive and cumulating negative streak

Formulas

```
[#ID] = ROW()-ROW(['# ID])+1
[negative] = IF([@['# ID]]=1,IF([@value]<0,1,0),IF([@value]<0,1+OFFSET([@negative],-1,0)),0))
```

How can keep this working when filtering some rows?, i want max negative streak (array formula) and [negative] and [ID ] column computing sequence and streak on visible rows. Here is the expected result:

**With filter**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table is located at `B6:E18`

Try this formulas:

In field [# ID]:

```
 = -1 + SUBTOTAL( 3, $D$6:$D7 )
```

In field [negative]:

```
 = IF( [@value] >= 0, 0,
 IF( [@['# ID]] = 1, 1,
 SUM( 1, INDEX( [negative], MATCH( -1 + [@['# ID]], ['# ID], 0 ) ) ) ) )
```

Max negative streak at `C2` (lo.Data is the name of the `Table`)

```
 =MAX( lo.Data[negative] )
```

[image]

[image]

Suggest to see the following pages for additional information about the functions used:
[Excel functions (alphabetical)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188)
[SUBTOTAL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939)
[INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)
[MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

Answer (score 0):

Add another IF to see if the row is hidden:

```
=IF(SUBTOTAL(3,[@Value])=0,..
```

This will return TRUE if hidden and FALSE if not hidden.

In the TRUE of the IF we use the value above:

```
=IF(SUBTOTAL(3,[@Value])=0,OFFSET([@Negative],-1,0),...
```

If not then we use your current formula:

```
=IF(SUBTOTAL(3,[@Value])=0,OFFSET([@Negative],-1,0),IF([@ID]=1,IF([@Value]<0,1,0),IF([@Value]<0,1+OFFSET([@Negative],-1,0),0)))
```

But this will error when the first value of the fitered data is negative, so we need to capture that with an IFERROR:

```
=IFERROR(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,[@Value])=0,OFFSET([@Negative],-1,0),IF([@ID]=1,IF([@Value]<0,1,0),IF([@Value]<0,1+OFFSET([@Negative],-1,0),0))),1)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

If you want ID to renumber with the filter also then use this for ID:

```
=IFERROR(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,[@Value])=0,OFFSET([@ID],-1,0),1+OFFSET([@ID],-1,0)),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Missing the formula for `[ID]`, once the `[ID]` formula is the adjusted then the formula for `[Negative]` does not return the correct value at line 16...

Comment: @EEM The ideal output does not change the ID, according to the picture.

Comment: The verbiage is not exactly clear and why I went off the picture.  But to appease you I added the ID

Comment: Appease yourself, just helping you to provide a complete answer.